# SET value in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql

How can i set the value in the WHERE clause. I'm using SQL Server MS.

```
DECLARE @Value INT;

SOMEPOINT:

INSERT $(TempTable)(Value, ...)
SELECT DISTINCT @Value, ...
FROM $(TempTable) t1
JOIN $(TempTable) t2 ON 
    t2.smth1 = t1.smth2

WHERE
    @Value = CASE WHEN t1.Value IS NULL THEN t2.Value ELSE t1.Value // so i want here to set the @Value value instead of ckecking it
        END

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 GOTO SOMEPOINT
```

I've tried a lot of things, nothing helped. If it is impossible to do this inside of WHERE clause what should i change?

Comment: what dbms is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set variables inside `WHERE` clause, but you can use the expression that computes the value:

```
INSERT $(TempTable)(Value, ...)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN t1.Value IS NULL THEN t2.Value ELSE t1.Value END AS Value
, ...
FROM $(TempTable) t1
JOIN $(TempTable) t2 ON 
    t2.smth1 = t1.smth2
```

This makes `Value` a "computed column" of your `SELECT DISTINCT` clause, making it eligible for insertion.

**Note:** [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) is more appropriate in situations when you provide a default value for `NULL` ([Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff))

```
INSERT $(TempTable)(Value, ...)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    COALESCE(t1.Value, t2.Value) AS Value
, ...
FROM $(TempTable) t1
JOIN $(TempTable) t2 ON 
    t2.smth1 = t1.smth2
```

Comment: yeah, it helped! Thanks!

Comment: The OP should use `COALESCE()` instead of `CASE`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you very much for your comment!